# Список с заданным количеством элементов в Twig

Tags: twig

Всем привет. Приходит массив с данными, Twig проходится по нему циклом и создаёт список с элементами. Как прописать условие, чтобы как только список заполнился 6 элементами, создавался новый список с ещё 6 элементами и т.д.?
Пробовала зайти со стороны JS, обрезала массив, создавала элемент... Получилась гора кода, возможно, такое решение упростит дело, но не уверена, что это задача для шаблонизатора.

```html
<ul class="clients__list">

  {% for item in items %}
  <li class="clients__list--item">
    <a href="{{ item.url }}"><img src="{{ item.img }}.{{ item.img_type }}" alt="{{ item.img_align }}" /></a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `array_chunk` сделайте входящему массиву и напишbте двойной цикл

Comment: Можно я вас помучаю и попрошу пояснение) Пока до меня не дошло

Comment: у вас входящий массив на N элементов. вам надо его вывести блоками по 6 элементов. Функция array_chunk разбивает массив на блоки нужной длины. Можете ее использовать для предварительной подготовки массива. Или вон в твиге есть batch-filter: `for list in items|batch(6)` выводим список, и потом `for item in list` выводим элементы

Comment: Для наглядности пока задала 3 элемента, т.к. в массиве их всего 6. Итого отрисовалось 6 списков. Сможете ткнуть меня, что не так? 

   {% for list in items|batch(3) %}
    {% for item in list %}
      <ul class="clients__list">
        <li class="clients__list--item">
          <a href="{{ item.url }}"><img src="{{ item.img }}.{{ item.img_type }}" alt="{{ item.name }}" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

Comment: Нашла свою ошибку, спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: посмотрите на свой код еще раз и подумайте в каком именно месте надо создавать новый список, а в каком выводить его элементы

Comment: если проблему свою решили, то оформите ответом. ссылки на документацию приветствуются

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось с помощью метода batch

```html
  {% for list in items|batch(3) %}
    <ul class="clients__list">
      {% for item in list %}
        <li class="clients__list--item">
          <a href="{{ item.url }}"><img src="{{ item.img }}.{{ item.img_type }}" alt="{{ item.name }}" /></a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```